# How are assumptions separated from condition in proof problems?

Tags: logic

This particular question struck me in that the first two assumptions, that $f$ is continuous and nonnegative, are grouped separately from the condition that the integral over $f$'s domain is $0$.
Would there be any information lost to re-word the proposition as:

('$f(x)$ is continuous' $\land$ '$f(x)$ is nonnegative' $\land \int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$) $\implies f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ ?

Comment: It would help if you included the question you refer to at the beginning, as is your statement seems correct but I don't really know what you were starting with

Comment: What you call "condition" are assumptions or hypotheses.

Comment: Logically speaking, all three of those assumptions/conditions have equivalent status. But in our minds we do often make the distinction between: background/contextual assumptions, like nonnegativity and continuity here, which just establish the setting for the assertion; and the "substantive" hypothesis, like the integral equaling $0$ here, which picks out the functions from the setting that we want to examine in the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From philosophical point of view, definitely yes; there is a significant difference.

From logical point of view, it depends on the availability of deduction theorem in a system.

In propositional calculus, the deduction theorem holds (its converse holds also):

> $H\cup\{P\}\vdash Q\;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;H\vdash P\rightarrow Q$

where $H$ is the set of propositions that represents assumptions, $P$ and $Q$ are any propositions. However, for example, in first-order predicate logic, deduction theorem holds with a proviso:

> $\Gamma,\phi\vdash\psi\;\;\Longrightarrow\;\;\Gamma\vdash\phi\rightarrow\psi$
> provided that $\psi$ is deduced with no application of generalisation
> on a variable that occurs free in $\phi$.

There are logical systems in which deduction theorem fails unconditionally.

All the statements of the given instance are closed formulas (sentences) evaluated in the interval $[a, b]$ (notice that the proper integral is logically a *variable-binding term operator*). Therefore, they are fit for propositions, $P, Q, R, S$ in propositional calculus as follows:

$P$ is $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x\in[a,b]$

$Q$ is $f(x)$ is nonnegative for all $x\in[a,b]$

$R$ is $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 0$

$S$ is $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Hence, the result: Two forms are equivalent and interchangeable.